# Conflito com o this que recebo na função quando clico, com o this do AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Como removo o conflito de variaveis? eu ja tentei colocar em uma variavel o THIS de fora para nao gerar conflito com o THIS do aJAx, mesmo assim nao mudeu nada!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Utilize uma variável global ou simplesmente `elemento.querySelector` ao invés do `this` usado para aplicar o `innerHTML`

Comment: variavel global nao adianta;

e selecionar pelo elemente nao e viavel porque existe varios

Comment: Se possível clica em [edit] e postar o código de como você está chamando a função; da função; etc. Fica mais fácil de analisar.

Comment: O this que você usa dentro da função, sempre será o da função. O que você precisa fazer ai é salvar o click em outra variável e usá-la. Ou seja, o inverso do que fez.

Comment: Considere editar sua pergunta adicionando o código ao invés de um "print" do editor.

Comment: Posta código e não imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas um exemplo, mas acredito que facilite a interpretação.

```
var thisdobotao = this;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   var thisdafuncao = this;

   thisdobotao.html('Carregando...')
};
```